# Trouble invoking MongoDB update using shell --eval switch from Powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am trying to invoke a MongoDB javascript fragment using the mongo.exe --eval command line switch. This works fine when run from the Windows command line, but I want to invoke it from a Powershell script like so:

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe`" localhost:27017/mydb --eval `"db.mydata.update({}, {`$set : {v : 1}})`" --quiet"
```

There is only one document in the mydata collection, and I want to set its `v` field to `1`. But, the above expression returns `SyntaxError: invalid property id (shell eval):1` when run from a Powershell script and does not update the document.

What makes this even more confusing is that the follow works as expected:

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe`" localhost:27017/mydb --eval `"printjson(db.mydata.findOne())`" --quiet"
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Update:

The solution:

```
Invoke-Expression '& "C:\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe" localhost:27017/mydb --eval "db.mydata.update({}, {`$set : {v : 2}})" --quiet'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes around the eval statement.

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI this isn't just specific to PowerShell, it's applicable to running mongo on any platform (Windows, OSX, etc)

Answer (score 0):

@Wes Freeman saved my day!

[MongoDB Reference mongo program use](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#use)

**Use single quotes (e.g. ') to enclose the JavaScript, as well as the additional JavaScript required to generate this output.**